# Recursive function in RISCV (RARS)

Tags: assembly, riscv

I'm new on this site and in mips.
I'm having trouble dealing with stacks recursively in MIPS.
I get the concept, but my program isn't reacting as I mean it to.
I try to make the sum of this function
[This function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAzrJ.png)

I delete the code about 1<x<=10.
Because it is similar to the code about 10<x<=20

```
function:
    
    beq a0,t1,equ0
    beq a0,t4,one
    bgt t1,a0,negative
    bgt t5,a0,twenty
    bgt t6,a0,ten
    bgt t4,a0,bigger_one

equ0:
    li a7,0
    jr ra
    j exit
one:
    li a7,1
    jr ra
    j exit
negative:
    li a7,-1
    j exit
twenty:
    addi sp,sp,-4
    sw ra,0(sp)
    #2x
    slli s0,a0,1
    addi sp,sp,-4
    sw s0,0(sp)
    #x/5
    addi sp,sp,-4
    sw ra,0(sp)
    addi s1,x0,5
    div a0,a0,s1
    jal function
    mul a0,a0,s1
    
    lw ra,0(sp)
    addi sp,sp,-4
    lw s7,0(sp)
    addi sp,sp,4
    
    add a7,s0,s7
    jr ra
    
ten:
    
    #x-2
    addi sp,sp,-4
    sw ra,0(sp)
    addi a0,a0,-2
    jal function
    addi a0,a0,2
    #restoring return address from stack
    lw ra,0(sp)
    sw a7,0(sp)
    #x-3
    addi sp,sp,-4
    sw ra,0(sp)
    addi a0,a0,-3
    jal function
    addi a0,a0,3
    
    lw ra,0(sp)
    addi sp,sp,4
    lw s7,0(sp)
    addi sp,sp,4
    
    add a7,a7,s7
    jr ra
```

The error message is :< execute terminate with errors>
It's too many recursive.
I have no idea to simplify this recursion code.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the logic doesn't terminate the recursion, then you'll get a stack overflow even if there is properly balanced stack handling.

```
    beq a0,t1,equ0
    beq a0,t4,one
    bgt t1,a0,negative
    bgt t5,a0,twenty       ******(a)
    bgt t6,a0,ten
    bgt t4,a0,bigger_one   
                           ******(b)
```

(a) Assuming `t5` holds ~20, this is says if 20 > x (in a0) then branch, or put another way if x < 20, then branch.  Probably not what you want.

(b) What do we do if we get here?  Since the prior instruction is a conditional branch, it could potentially not branch (i.e. fall through).  This is just to say that the logic is overly complicated.  The last case should either be an unconditional branch, or simply a fall through to the following code, a properly placed case that is the only possibility left after the other tests.

2. It doesn't look like you have properly balanced stack handling.  For every push there need to be a corresponding pop.  The pop's need to balance the push's dynamically in amount.

In the case of `twenty:` you have 4 pushes and only 1 pop.

---

FYI, the following combo is illogical:

```
jr ra
j exit
```

The `jr ra` is an unconditional branch, so that makes the `j exit` unreachable, aka [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code).